# Character Counter using Array List

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I need to design a program that reads in an ASCII text file and creates an output file that contains each unique ASCII character and the number of times it appears in the file. Each unique character in the file must be represented by a character frequency class instance. The character frequency objects must be stored in an array list. My code is below:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ASCII
{
    class CharacterFrequency
    {
        char ch;
        int frequency;
        public char getCharacter()
        {
            return ch;
        }
        public void setCharacter(char ch)
        {
            this.ch = ch;
        }
        public int getfrequency()
        {
            return frequency;
        }
        public void setfrequency(int frequency)
        {
            this.frequency = frequency;
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            string OutputFileName;
            string InputFileName;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path");
            InputFileName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the outputfile name");
            OutputFileName = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName);

            string data = File.ReadAllText(InputFileName);


            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

            //create two for loops to traverse through the arraylist and compare

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                int k = 0;
                int f = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (data[i].Equals(data[j]))
                    {
                        f++;                        
                        if (i > j) { k++; }
                    }
                }


                al.Add(data[i] + "(" + (int)data[i] + ")" + f + " ");

                foreach (var item in al)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(item);
                }


            }


            streamWriter.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the program does not stop running and the output file keeps getting larger until it eventually runs out memory and I get an error stating that. I am not seeing where the error is or why the loop won't terminate. It should just count the characters but it seems to keep looping and repeating counting the characters. Any help?

Comment: “The character frequency objects must be stored in an array list” Why? That `CharacterFrequency` class is rather strange as well. Is this C# or Java?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hcALTD

Comment: Pull that last foreach out from inside the for loop

Comment: If it’s meant to be C# instead of Java use properties instead of getXXX and setXXX methods and use type-safe List<> over the obsolete ArrayList. For example your whole block before the Main method can be reduced to two lines: `public char Character { get; set; }` and `public int Frequency { get; set; }`.

Comment: Hmm, the ArrayList is so awkward. Can you get away with also including an object for every [C0 Control and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character, regardless if it is in the input? That way you can pre-populate it and index it directly based on Char value. When you dump to file, just skip the ones with frequency == 0.

Comment: I am guessing this was down-voted because using the debugger to see where errors occur is basic debugging skill. Take this opportunity to learn to use the debugger better.

Comment: @radarbob the thing is there is no error happening, its just the output I am getting is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace yourNamespace
{
    class Char_frrequency
    {
    Dictionary<Char, int> countMap = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    public String getStringWithUniqueCharacters(String input)
    {

        List<Char> uniqueList = new List<Char>();


        foreach (Char x in input)
        {
            if (countMap.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                countMap[x]++;
            }
            else
            {
                countMap.Add(x, 1);
            }


            if (!uniqueList.Contains(x))
            {
                uniqueList.Add(x);
            }
        }
        Char[] uniqueArray = uniqueList.ToArray();
        return new String(uniqueArray);
    }

    public int getFrequency(Char x)
    {
        return countMap[x];
    }
}
}
```

This might not be the ideal solution. But you can use these methods

Comment: Ah, I see you are reading "unique character" as "character occurring exactly once." I think it means to make a different count for each different character value.

Comment: Since my `countMap` contains only the characters that occurred in the input string, you can get all the unique characters by iterating through the countMap key List

Comment: You should modify your answer and delete the `uniqueList` because as you point out it is not necessary. Leaving it in only confuses the issue. The key insight is how a `Dictionary` naturally captures all the unique characters. DO NOT allow client code to iterate `countMap`. Client code should only be calling methods and not manipulating internal state or have access to any class properties/fields. Add a `OccursOnce` method to `Char_frrequency`.